# Not able to connect to wurstmeister/kafka

Tags: docker, apache-kafka, docker-compose

I am running wurstmeister/kafka in a ubuntu 14.04 LTS machine. Kafka container is running fine. However I am not able to connect my microservice to this container.

Kafka docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: user1/zookeeper:3.4.9
    ports:
      - "2181:2181"
  kafka:
    image: my-kafka
    ports:
      - "9092:9092"
    hostname: kafka-01
    environment:
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_PORT: 9092
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME: "kafka-01"
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:2181
      KAFKA_CREATE_TOPICS: "topic1:1:1,topic2:1:1"
    volumes:
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock
```

docker-compose for microservice(myapp):

```
version: '2'

services:
  myapp:
    network_mode: 'bridge'
    extends:
      file: myapp.base.yml
      service: myapp
    links:
      - kafka

  zookeeper:
    network_mode: 'bridge'
    extends:
      file: zookeeper.yml
      service: zookeeper

  kafka:
    network_mode: 'bridge'
    extends:
      file: kafka.yml
      service: kafka
    links:
      - zookeeper
```

I have linked kafka in an env:

```
kafkaHost=kafka-01:9092
```

Please let me know what am I doing wrong or if more info is required. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The hostname should be what you specified in "links", ie. "kafka".  As @dnephin said the hostname is not needed.  I think what you want is actually KAFKA_ADVERTISED_HOST_NAME environment variable.

What version of docker do you have?  I am using docker 1.12.3 on Mac OS with no issues.

You might also want to try the Confluent docker images:

- https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-kafka/
- https://hub.docker.com/r/confluentinc/cp-zookeeper/

Here's my sample docker compose file:

```
version: "2"
services:
  web:
    image: nginx:latest
    links: 
      - kafka
  zookeeper:
    extends:
      file: kafka-services.yml
      service: zookeeper
  kafka:
    extends:
      file: kafka-services.yml
      service: kafka
    depends_on:
      - zookeeper
```

My base kafka services compose file (kafka-services.yml):

```
version: '2'
services:
  zookeeper:
    image: confluentinc/cp-zookeeper:latest
    ports:
      - "32181:32181"
    environment:
      ZOOKEEPER_CLIENT_PORT: 32181
      ZOOKEEPER_TICK_TIME: 2000

  kafka:
    image: confluentinc/cp-kafka:latest
    ports:
     - "29092:29092"
    environment:
      KAFKA_BROKER_ID: 1
      KAFKA_ZOOKEEPER_CONNECT: zookeeper:32181
      KAFKA_ADVERTISED_LISTENERS: PLAINTEXT://kafka:29092
```

Comment: I used confluentinc kafka and zk images and updated my compose files as per your suggestion. Now, getting this exception:

[2016-11-02 06:54:58,267] WARN [Controller-1-to-broker-1-send-thread], Controller 1's connection to broker kafka:29092 (id: 1 rack: null) was unsuccessful (kafka.controller.RequestSendThread)

kafka_1         | java.io.IOException: Connection to kafka:29092 (id: 1 rack: null) failed

Comment: @falcon01: what's your docker version?

Comment: I $ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.9.0-rc3, build fcd38d3
docker-py version: 1.10.6
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016

Comment: here's my version

Comment: $ docker-compose version
docker-compose version 1.9.0-rc3, build fcd38d3
docker-py version: 1.10.6
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016

Comment: docker-compose version 1.7.1, build 0a9ab35
docker-py version: 1.8.1
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

Comment: @falcon01 I am not able to reproduce your error with the above compose file on ubuntu trusty.

Comment: my docker-compose version: docker-compose version 1.8.1, build 878cff1
docker-py version: 1.10.3
CPython version: 2.7.9
OpenSSL version: OpenSSL 1.0.1e 11 Feb 2013

Answer (score 0):

The `hostname` field does not set the public hostname, it sets the internal container hostname. It's generally not that useful.

Hostnames are automatically provided by docker networking, use `kafka` as the hostname.

Comment: tried both ways. removed hostname from and then set it as `kafka`. I am getting:
o.a.kafka.common.network.Selector Selector.java:276 - Error in I/O with kafka/172.17.42.10 java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.checkConnect(Native Method)
at sun.nio.ch.SocketChannelImpl.finishConnect(SocketChannelImpl.java:717)
at org.apache.kafka.common.network.Selector.poll(Selector.java:238)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.NetworkClient.poll(NetworkClient.java:192)
at org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.internals.Sender.run(Sender.java:191)

Comment: You might also have to retry the connection, as it's not necessarily available immediately. https://docs.docker.com/compose/startup-order/